# Как перемещать объект в зависимости от угла поворота? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, разработка-игр

У меня есть объект player, который хранит информацию об объекте игрока: его координата по х, у и его угол поворота. Как я могу двигать его в зависимости от угла поворота? Что нужно для этого использовать? Есть ли какая-то формула для рассчёта разницы координат?

Comment: Слушай, тут тебе нужно в векторную алгебру чуть углубиться. Я тоже птсал небольшой игровой проектик. Там  без этого никуда. Это, кстати, к вопросу "да нахрен мне эта математика нужна". Там ничего сложного, но почитать придётся.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Небольшой пример с обычным дивом. Движение на **W**.

```js
window.focus()

const T = Math.PI * 2

const player = {
  x: [0, 0],
  y: [0, 0],
  size: 80,
  angle: 0,
  speed: 10
}

update()

onmousemove = e => {
  const dx = e.x - (player.x[1] + player.size / 2)
  const dy = e.y - (player.y[1] + player.size / 2)
  player.angle = (Math.atan2(dy, dx) + T) % T
  el.style.setProperty('--a', player.angle + 'rad')

}

onkeydown = e => {
  if (e.key === 'w' || e.key === 'ц') {
    player.x[0] += player.speed * Math.cos(player.angle)
    player.y[0] += player.speed * Math.sin(player.angle)
  }
}

function ease(arr, v = 0.2) {
  arr[1] += (arr[0] - arr[1]) * v
}

function update() {
  requestAnimationFrame(update)

  ease(player.x)
  ease(player.y)

  el.style.setProperty('--x', player.x[1] + 'px')
  el.style.setProperty('--y', player.y[1] + 'px')
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

div {
  --size: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
  background: black;
  transform: translate(var(--x), var(--y)) rotate(var(--a));
}

div::before,
div::after {
  --size: 30px;
  content: "";
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
}

div::before {
  top: 0;
}

div::after {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div style="--x: 0; --y: 0; --a: 0;" id="el"></div>
```

Comment: кнопку конечно подобрали удачно)

Comment: @ᅠhᅠОтличная работа! Клавиши A S D поленился сделать?

Comment: @Alexandr_TT не, мне казалось вопрос подразумевает какой-то один триггер движения

Comment: @ᅠhᅠ Ну можно добавить например вращение по осям, увеличение Сейчас, конечно очень здорово смотрится при нажатой клавише W иконка бегает за курсором. Но может ещё что-нибудь покруче сделать?

Comment: @Alexandr_TT да не, всё остальное увеличит и без того непонятный код.

Comment: @ᅠhᅠну может быть добавить срабатывание **W** в русской раскладке? Уже смотрю сделал :) Прямо телепат ты

Comment: @Alexandr_TT я опередил твой вопрос ))

Comment: предлагаю добавить еще requestFocus, да и ходить кажется надо просто по mousedown или вообще всегда, а когда догонит - ставить cursor: none

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я даже не знаю что это такое. Завтра почитаю, а сегодня я пошел баиньки. Всех целую, всем пока

Comment: @StrangerintheQ а что это requestFocus ? Ты имел ввиду типа фокусировку на body сделать?

Comment: @ᅠhᅠ ага, чтобы кликать не гадо было, а то не работают клавиши

Comment: @StrangerintheQ а как это сделать? у меня, если честно, в голове пусто на этот счёт

Comment: @ᅠhᅠ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/focus

Comment: @StrangerintheQ так оно же не работает с дивом.

Comment: можно window.focus()